# How to data from one form to another in MS Access 13

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database in MS Access 13 in which there are 2 forms "Project List" and "Completed Project". In the project list form I have a dropdown in "Status" field in which there are 2 options "Completed" or "InProgress". Now I want to move data to another form on the basis of Dropdown option selected. For example, In "Project List" form when if I select Status as Completed then it removes that project from Project List form and move that project into Competed Project form. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If forms are based on the same source table (Projects), but use different queries - full table for "Project List" and completed only for "Completed Project", just change first query to exclude completed projects. Now if you change status and requery both forms, completed project will "move" to second form.